# Floating point precision of scipy.solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am using `scipy.solve_ivp` with `RK45` as an integrator and I was wondering whether `scipy` and all its sub-routines use 64-bit double-precision everywhere or whether precision is reduced anywhere in the code?

Comment: How would you reduce precision in python without a lot of effort? RK45 is a recent implementation as full python code, there is no `float32` left over from hypothetical legacy code. // But anyway, always carefully set the error tolerances `atol` and `rtol`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. `atol` and `rtol` are somewhat delicate though. Do you have any advice on how to set them correctly?

Comment: Set `atol=scale*rtol` where `scale` is the average expected magnitude of the components. This fails if the components individually have wildly different scales. Then it often helps to rescale the system so that the components exposed to `solve_ivp` have again scales within 2 or 3 powers of 10 among each other.

Comment: Right, that seems sensible. But what about setting rtol?

Comment: That depends on if you just want a quick plot or reliable numbers. 1e-4 could be sufficient for an overview, standard is 1e-6 to 1e-8, for high accuracy 1e-11 seems to work well and 1e-14 gets often rejected as not feasible with double floats.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Is is possible to work with precision higher than 1e-14? Any alternative to using double floats?

Comment: I would say no, the relative precision can not exceed the possibilities of the data type. If the scales of the problem are accordingly, the absolute precision can of course be lower. The step-size heuristics may suffer with extremely small or large scales. // The solve_ivp steppers are all implemented in python. I do not know if that is sufficient to use them with multi-precision data types, one would have to test this.